# finding subsequence in a sequence sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a query to help me find all occurrences of a specific sequence in a table of ordered sets.
for example, if i have a sequence: (3, 4) and two ordered sets: "my first set" (1,**3,4**,5,**3,4**) and "my second set" (5,**3,4**) the query will return the index of each occurrence in the set - the index is the general id of the table and not an inner index of the set. If there are more sets but they don't contain the sequence, they won't appear.

Maybe a demonstration with tables will be more intuitive:
I have a set table (set_tbl):

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | my first set |
| 2 | my second set |
| 3 | my third set |

set data (set_data_tbl):

| id | set_id | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | 4 |
| 7 | 2 | 5 |
| 8 | 2 | 3 |
| 9 | 2 | 4 |
| 10 | 3 | 5 |
| 11 | 3 | 3 |
| 12 | 3 | 9 |

and a sequence table (seq_tbl)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | my first sequence |
| 2 | my second sequence |

sequence data (sequence_data_tbl):

| id | sequence_id | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 9 |

so for sequence id 1 the output should be:

| set_name | set_id | position (taken from id of set_data_tbl) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| my first set | 1 | 2 |
| my first set | 1 | 5 |
| my second set | 2 | 8 |

I've been working on this long time but couldn't form a query that might even start doing something like that. I hope this is enough to understand what I am facing.
Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not quite following the logic.  How do you define the sequences you are looking for?  Also, there are two tables named seq_data_tbl, with different data in them.  Where does the row (id, sequence_id, number) = (3, 2, 9) come into play?

Comment: I've changed the names of the tables. basically I have two objects Ordered Set and Sequence. The difference between the two is that the Ordered Set is larger in size than the sequence but their logic is the same, they both hold set of numbers in a specific order. I'd like to find the occurrences of a specific sequence (specified by its ID) in all existing sets.
In the example I provided there are three sets 1: (1,3,4,5,3,4), 2:(5,3,4), 3:(5,3,9) and two sequences: 1: (3,4), 2:(9). looking for the occurrences of seq 1 in the sets should provide the output table in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach . . . use strings.

The idea is to concatenate all the numbers starting from the current row to the end of the rows for each set.

Then aggregate the sequences into strings and compare them using `like`.

There are some tricks, so that "1" does not match "10". And Postgres does not (yet) support string aggregation with window functions.  But here is an example:

```
select sd.*, s.*
from set_data_tbl sd cross join lateral
     (select string_agg(sd2.number::text, ',' order by sd2.id) as numbers
      from set_data_tbl sd2
      where sd2.set_id = sd.set_id and sd2.id >= sd.id
     ) sd2 join
     (select s.sequence_id, string_agg(s.number::text, ',' order by s.id) as numbers
      from sequence_data_tbl s
      group by s.sequence_id
     ) s
     on sd2.numbers || ',' like s.numbers || ',%';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b932ea2d13836fef8e83c3a0821efe1) is a db<>fiddle.

There is also a set-based approach, which should have better performance and actually looks simpler:

```
select sd.set_id, s.sequence_id, (sd.id - seqnum), s.cnt, min(sd.id)
from set_data_tbl sd join
     (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by sequence_id order by id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by sequence_id) as cnt
      from sequence_data_tbl s
     ) s
     on sd.number = s.number 
group by sd.set_id, s.sequence_id, (sd.id - seqnum), s.cnt
having s.cnt = count(*)
order by min(sd.id);
```

What is this doing?

It is matching each set to each sequence number.  But before doing so, it is enumerating the sequence rows, so they are ordered starting from 1.

Then is uses a trick reminiscent of solving some gaps-and-islands problems.  Adjacent rows match when the difference between the `id` in the set table and the enumerated value is constant.  Voila!  Count the number of these and you have a match when the right number of rows match.

Note:  This assumes that the `id` in the set table has no gaps.  If that is allowed, you could just replace it with a sequence number defined by `row_number()`.